# Asp.net server controls in webmatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

It seems asp.net server controls such as calendar cannot seem to work in webmatrix.

Is there any equivalent api or anything that would be similar to those which I can use. I am trying to add a calendar for my site for a booking system in webmatrix but I cannot seem to find any calendar related controls besides the 30boxes api which is not very relevant to what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Javascript Calendar Widget or something like that. Many exists but are not "controls" per se.  If you want an API I think both Google and Yahoo Calendar have easy copy past calendar widget's.  You will need an account to run either under.